# Prove that two norms are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have two norms $||f||_{C^{1} ([0,1])} = \max \{||f||_{\infty}; ||f'||_{\infty}   \}$ where $ C^{1} ([0,1]) = \{ f : [0,1] \to \mathbf{R}: \text{f has continuous derivative on }   [0,1] \}$ and the second norm defined by: $||f||_{0} =  |f(0)| + ||f'||_{\infty}$ for $f \in C^{1} ([0,1])$. My goal is to prove/disprove these norms are equivalent. I know the definition of equivalent norms is that there exists a constant Lipschitz $c \geq 1$ between two of them. I attempt to find the example to disprove this which is the sequence of function: $f_{n}(x) = \sin(nx)$, but it is not. Is there a hint/way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

$\|f\|_0 \leq 2\|f\|_{C^{1}[0,1]}$ is obvious. For the other way use the fact that $|f(x)|=|f(0)+\int_0^{x} f'(t)dt| \leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}$ for all $x$ which gives $\|f\|_{C^{1}[0,1]} \leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}=\|f\|_0$.